# Is there a better way to track float input in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, input, floating-point

I've been trying to get an input system that only accepts floats, and I have a system that works, but I'm not sure it's the best way to go about it. The code below is my current system:

```
def InputExample():

try:

  example = float(input("Input a number: "))

except ValueError:
  print("Please enter a number.")

  InputExample()
```

Is there a better way to go about this? This current system works, but it feels kind of clunky, especially with multiple in a row all tracking separate input systems for float values, i.e.

```
def InputExample():

  try:

    example = float(input("Input a number: "))

  except ValueError:
    print("Please enter a number.")

    InputExample()

def InputExample2():

  try:

    example2 = float(input("Input a number(2): "))

  except ValueError:
    print("Please enter a number.")

    InputExample2()
```

And I'm sure you can imagine how clunky this gets with 2, 3, 4 of these. Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: What you are doing is recursion, which is not good for this purpose. Consider using iteration (e.g. a `while` loop).

Comment: Have your first `InputExample()` function `return float(input("Input a number: "))`, so that it inputs one number and returns it.  Then just call that function multiple times -- have the caller do `example1, example2 = InputExample(), InputExample()`.  Or make a list with `examples = [InputExample() for _ in range(4)]` or whatever.